# Count invoices created in next 6 Months after current invoice for each customer - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have data set where I need to count invoices created within next 6 months a invoice is created including any other invoice created on same day. This is some sample data:

| Customer | Invoice | Date | Expected Ans |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 3/1/2021 | 3 |
| 1 | C | 5/1/2021 | 3 |
| 1 | D | 8/1/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | E | 8/1/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | F | 10/1/2021 | 0 |
| 2 | Z | 1/1/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | Y | 5/1/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | X | 5/1/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | W | 10/1/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | V | 10/1/2021 | 1 |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don’t link to images, provide all information as editable text in your question. Provide sample data, the result you want to achieve and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you want to count the number of rows that occur within the next 6 months per customer. Using that logic, I got your expected results.

### Counting Future Invoices Within 6 Months Per Customer

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Invoice 

CREATE TABLE #Invoice
(
    Customer INT
    ,Invoice CHAR(1)
    ,InvoiceDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO #Invoice
VALUES
(1,'A','2021-01-01')
,(1,'B','2021-03-01')
,(1,'C','2021-05-01')
,(1,'D','2021-08-01')
,(1,'E','2021-08-01')
,(1,'F','2021-10-01')
,(2,'Z','2021-01-01')
,(2,'Y','2021-05-01')
,(2,'X','2021-05-01')
,(2,'W','2021-10-01')
,(2,'V','2021-10-01')


SELECT *
FROM #Invoice AS A
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS InvoiceCnt
    FROM #Invoice AS DTA
    WHERE A.Customer = DTA.Customer /*Match on same customer*/
    AND A.Invoice <> DTA.Invoice /*Don't join row to self*/
    AND A.InvoiceDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-6,DTA.InvoiceDate) AND DTA.InvoiceDate /*Look for invoices within 6 months*/
) AS B
```

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as accepted so others know your question has been answered
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%201%20Choose%20one%20answer,or%20simply%20un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.